# Body Parser resulting in undefined

Tags: javascript, express, post, body-parser

Trying to do a simple console.log of the body of a POST request. I see the payload in my Chrome console with the correct data but when I try to read it I get the following error:

```
express_1  | TypeError: Cannot read property 'exampleval' of undefined
```

I have used this exact logic in the past and never had an issue.

**services/router.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const http = require('http');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();
    // parse application/json
    app.use(bodyParser.json());                        

    // parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
const router = new express.Router();
const employees = require('../controllers/employees.js');


//router.route('/employees').post(employees.post);

router.post('/employees', function (req, res) {
    var exampleval = req.body.exampleval;
    console.log(exampleval);
})

module.exports = router;
```

**services/web-server.js**

```
const http = require('http');
const express = require('express');
const webServerConfig = require('../config/web-server.js');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const router = require('./router.js');
const morgan = require('morgan');
const cors = require('cors');


let httpServer;

function initialize() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const app = express();
    httpServer = http.createServer(app);
    // Combines logging info from request and response
    app.use(morgan('combined'));
    // enable cors on all routes
    app.use(cors())
    // Mount the router at /api so all its routes start with /api
    app.use('/api', router);
    // Body Parser
    app.use(bodyParser.json());
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));

    httpServer.listen(webServerConfig.port)
      .on('listening', () => {
        console.log(`Web server listening on localhost:${webServerConfig.port}`);

        resolve();
      })
      .on('error', err => {
        reject(err);
      });
  });
}

module.exports.initialize = initialize;

function close() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      httpServer.close((err) => {
        if (err) {
          reject(err);
          return;
        }

        resolve();
      });
    });
  }

module.exports.close = close;
```

I believe these are the only 2 relevant portions of code. Any advice would be greatly appreciated as I feel like I am very close. My hope is to eventually then pass these values to be used in a SQL query.

Comment: You created an app with the body parser in services/router.js, attach body parsing middleware to it, and discard it. Since the body parser is also attached to the app actually used (in services/web-server.js), it’s not the source of the problem, but it is weird.

Comment: Ill also throw out that instantiating a new express app and adding body parser middleware in `services/router.js` is completely redundant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Middleware order matters.

```
// Mount the router at /api so all its routes start with /api
app.use('/api', router);
// Body Parser
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
```

should be

```
// Body Parser
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
// Mount the router at /api so all its routes start with /api
app.use('/api', router);
```

so that the router only receives requests (that it might want to handle) after the body parser has attached `req.body`.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!!